# Spring Boot + Grails shared Hibernate 2nd level cache

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, grails

I have a monolithic webservice that I plan to convert into smaller micro-services over time. The app is currently written in Grails but the micro-services don't need all of what Grails offers and so the idea is to use a more lightweight framework (if at all). To offload work from the database the Hibernate second level cache shall be used as well.

Before any of that is going to happen, I started to play around with distributed/clustered caches and different frameworks, to learn if what is planned is actually feasible. Since Grails cannot be replaced all at once, one test app is written in Grails and the second one uses Spring Boot.

Both are configured to use Hibernate 4.3.11.Final and define a simple domain class/JPA entity.

### Spring Boot

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "gr_test_cache")
@Cacheable
public class GrTestCache implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;

    @Version
    long version;

    String name;

    // Constructor, Getter, Setter
}
```

### Grails

```java
class GrTestCache implements Serializable {

    long id
    long version

    String name

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }
}
```

For caching, Hazelcast v3.7.2 is used and when I run either application on different machines they share the cache and therefore loading an entity from DB on app-1 results in the same request on app-2 to be served from the cache. This, however only works among the Spring and Grails applications. Trying to fetch an entity that was cached by the Spring app results in an error in the Grails app and vice versa.

Spring error reading Grails cached entity:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field GrTestCache.name to java.lang.Long
```

Grails error reading Spring cached entity:

```
property.BasicPropertyAccessor HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: GrTestCache, setter method of property: version
property.BasicPropertyAccessor HHH000091: Expected type: long, actual value: java.lang.String
```

Unfortunately I haven't yet found a solution to look into the cache to see the data that is there, but to me it looks like, although the domain objects seem to be the same, both apps store different formats in the cache which results in errors in de-serialization.

The question now is: is there any way such interoperability can be achieved or do I have to stick with all Grails or all Spring (or whatever...)? Doing the caching manually to have full control is out of the question.

*edit*

As asked for, some DAO code. I don't think it's relevant, but here you go.

### Spring Boot

SpTestCacheRepository.java

```java
public interface SpTestCacheRepository extends CrudRepository<GrTestCache, Long> {
}
```

SpTestCacheService.java

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public class SpTestCacheService {

    private SpTestCacheRepository cacheRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SpTestCacheService(SpTestCacheRepository cacheRepository) {
        this.cacheRepository = cacheRepository;
    }

    public GrTestCache testCache(long id) {
        return cacheRepository.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

### Grails

```java
@Transactional
class GrTestCacheService {

    def fetchTestCache(def params) {
        log.trace "->fetchTestCache <params: $params>"
        return GrTestCache.get(params.id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you shore repository/DAO code?

Comment: One additional comment: I'm not only interested in Grails + Spring Boot but more generally in Grails + "Any other app that uses Hibernate". Spring Boot was just my go-to framework for this test.

Comment: Try changing `id` and `version` type from `long` to `Long`. Some times primitive types can cause issues with serialization/deserialization mechanism